# Example of code with pypgen (python)

Tags: bioinformatics, population-genetics, genomics, population-dynamics

I have a VCF file and wish to calculate a few indices of population divergence over a sliding window.

I consider using [pypgen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypgen) but the documentation is currently very limited. Can you please give me an example (for Jost'D for example) of a code that would work?

Comment: vcftools can compute a few things in sliding windows (Tajima's D, Pi, Fst, LD at least), but that's probably not enough, is it?

Comment: Nope it is not indeed. It cannot calculate Jost's D or Dxy for example. There is also EggLib (for which I am currently reading the documentation).